# Testing for bias with variable odds

Tags: probability, statistics

The situation is for an electronic racing game.

At the beginning of each race, 6 racers are given a random probability of winning (which add up to 100%). The probability of each racer is shown, and then the positions of the racers are shown at the end.

I want to test if the probabilities shown are accurate, or if there is some bias.

Comment: I think this is too vague.  All you record is the size of the sector?  Well, say the wheel always stops at the same point.  Very biased wheel.  But in that case the probability that the fixed point is in a given sector is proportional to the size of that sector (appropriately measured), so you get the same distribution that a uniform wheel would get.

Comment: @lulu updated the question. My problem is that you can't use the same method for testing if a dice/coin is biased, by listing out each outcome and then seeing if it appears 1/6th or 1/2 of the time.

Comment: The update doesn't change anything.  Instead of a single point, just imagine that it always comes up in some extremely small sector.  I think you need information about the location of the sectors.  That said, if you have some precise situation in mind, you should edit to add that structure.

Comment: @lulu updated again. Hopefully it makes more sense :)

Comment: Well, that's a very different question.  If there is no consistency between different races, it is hard to say much.  One simple strategy is to bet (virtually) on, say, the first named racer in every race.  Your virtual bet should pay fairly at the given probability (so it costs you $1$ each round and you win $\frac 1p$ if your racer wins, where $p$ is the nominal probability).   If things are on the up and up, that strategy, played out over a large number of games, should have expectation $0$.  Does it?  If it is a systematic winner or loser over the long haul, then there is a bias.

Comment: @lulu that strategy is what I was looking for, thanks.